# "Reading" section from careers profile as a separate page

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

I like "Reading" section on Careers profile and I would like to invest more time in it and make it my primary place for reviews of technical literature.

I would love if it would be possible to have a link to the page (same as link a to the CV) containing *only* "Reading" section, without other personal data around it. If that would've been possible I would link from my website to this page and I would have great incentive to maintain the quality of the entries in the "Reading" section.

Will Careers ever have this feature?